# Looping through rows, creating and reusing multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am building a streambed hydrology calculator in R using multiple tables from an Access database. I am having trouble automating and calculating the same set of indices for multiple sites. The following sample dataset describes my data structure:

```
> Thalweg
   StationID    AB0 AB1 AB2 AB3 AB4 AB5 BC1 BC2 BC3 BC4 Xdep_Vdep
1  1AAUA017.60   47  45  44  55  54   6  15  39  15  11  18.29
2  1AXKR000.77   30  27  24  19  20  18   9  12  21  13  6.46
3  2-BGU005.95   52  67  62  42  28  25  23  26  11  19  20.18
4  2-BLG011.41   66  85  77  83  63  35  10  70  95  90  67.64
5  2-CSR003.94   29  35  46  14  19  14  13  13  21  48  6.74
```

where each column represents certain field-measured parameters (i.e. depth of a reach section) and each row represents a different site.

I have successfully used the apply functions to simultaneously calculate simple functions on multiple rows:

```
> Xdepth <- apply(Thalweg[, 2:11], 1, mean) # Mean Depth
> Xdepth
   1    2    3    4    5 
33.1 19.3 35.5 67.4 25.2
```

and appending the results back to the proper station in a dataframe.

However, I am struggling when I want to calculate and save variables that are subsequently used for further calculations. I cannot seem to loop or apply the same function to multiple columns on a single row and complete the same calculations over the next row without mixing variables and data.

I want to do:

```
Residual_AB0 <- min(Xdep_Vdep, Thalweg$AB0)
Residual_AB1 <- min((Residual_AB0 + other_variables), Thalweg$AB1)
Residual_AB2 <- min((Residual_AB1 + other_variables), Thalweg$AB2)
Residual_AB3 <- min((Residual_AB2 + other_variables), Thalweg$AB3) 
# etc.
Depth_AB0 <- (Thalweg$AB0 - Residual_AB0)
Depth_AB1 <- (Thalweg$AB1 - Residual_AB1)
Depth_AB2 <- (Thalweg$AB2 - Residual_AB2)
# etc.
```

I have tried and subsequently failed at for loops such as:

```
for (i in nrow(Thalweg)){
  Residual_AB0 <- min(Xdep_Vdep, Thalweg$AB0)
  Residual_AB1 <- min((Residual_AB0 + Stacks_Equation), Thalweg$AB1)
  Residual_AB2 <- min((Residual_AB1 + Stacks_Equation), Thalweg$AB2)
  Residual_AB3 <- min((Residual_AB2 + Stacks_Equation), Thalweg$AB3)
  Residuals <- data.frame(Thalweg$StationID, Residual_AB0, Residual_AB1, Residual_AB2, Residual_AB3)
}
```

Is there a better way to approach looping through multiple lines of data when I need unique variables saved for each specific row that I am currently calculating? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please update your code to provide a working example by replacing `other_variables` and `Stacks_Equation` with actual code.

Comment: The Stacks_Equation variable is queried from the Access Database, so it is an integer unique to each site (row of data) that must be applied across each row and a new Stacks_Equation variable used for subsequent rows. Same applies for the "other_variables" - they are all integers queried with the original dataset and in column format like the Xdep_Vdep column

Answer (score 0):

your exact problem is still a mistery to me...
but it looks like you want a double for loop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(thalweg)){
  residual=thalweg[i,"Xdep_Vdep"]
  for(j in 2:11){
    residual=min(residual,thalweg[i,j])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that part of the code actually works easily with the provided apply() function. I am looking for a way to calculate, for example, Residual_ABO using data (integers) queried from Access, use Residual_AB0 in a subsequent calculation (Residual_AB1), use Residual_AB1 for Residual_AB2, etc. for a single row. When I try looping the min() command searches my entire database for the smallest number in each column and outputs calculations based on that, not min of exactly what is called for in the (). I want those commands to work on distinct lines of data and not mix sites (rows).